# ZIP extension needs to be loaded in opencart

Tags: php, installation, opencart

I am installing opencart 2.0.1.1 on my hosting but during installation step-2 it says  ***Warning: ZIP extension needs to be loaded for OpenCart to work!*** 
I did my search on it but everyone is saying that it is server issue.[image]

I am really stuck at this point. I am newbie in opencart but did my OC installation many time on localhost. Please if anyone have some experience related this issue kindly guide me.

Comment: my suggestion... do not install OC2.0.1.1. This version has a lot of bugs. The best, if you install at least 2.3.0.2 version.

Comment: Anything unclear about the error message? Did you install that extension?

Comment: @NicoHaase the problem was very simple and I was naive at that time. I had to turn on zip extension from php.ini

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolve this issue by different way.

- Install my opencart on localhost
- using ftp, I uploaded it to my server
- did some changes in ***config.php*** and ***admin/config.php***
- Export my database from ***localhost/phpmyadmin***
- Created database at my live server and imported my database, which I exported from localhost

And I am good to go :)

Answer (score 6):

The following command on ubuntu environment resolved my problem:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip
```

Comment: Yes, @Idriz, that solved it for me. Don't forget to restart apache `sudo service apache2 restart` so that the new module can become functional.

Comment: Also check your php version. 7.2 is now out.

Answer (score 4):

Re: Warning: ZIP extension needs to be loaded for OpenCart to work!

If you use Cpanel ( Linux base hosting )

On software go to the "Select PHP Version" and check mark the ZIP

It is take 4-5 minutes to update

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, we want to check php.ini file path like similar version or not.
Ex: `php7.3 means /etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini` please make sure it.
Otherwise, we want to run following command:

```
sudo a2dismod php5.6 (Your php.ini file path version)
sudo a2enmod php7.3
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Then check now, it's working fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install the opencart on your local machine (Windows OS)
Just go to the XAMPP control panel > Apache row click the > config button > edit PHP (php.ini) > search zip and uncomment the zip line and save it and restart the Apache server